# response.responseText adds previous responseText (node.js, prototype)

Tags: ajax, node.js, prototypejs

This is my node.js function that uses res.write:

```
function: ping(){
    res.write(JSON.stringify({"datatype":"ping"}));
    setTimeout(ping, 30000);
}
```

This is the client, request written in prototype:

```
    this.pushconnection = new Ajax.Request(pushserveraddress, {
        method: 'get',
        evalJSON: 'false',
        onInteractive: this.pushconnectionInteractive.bind(this)
    });
}

pushconnectionInteractive: function(response) {
}
```

The problem is that `response.responseText` will grow with every `res.write` that comes through.

Example:

```
1st ping() received: response.responseText = {"datatype":"ping"}

2nd ping() received: response.responseText = {"datatype":"ping"}{"datatype":"ping"}

3rd ping() received: response.responseText = {"datatype":"ping"}{"datatype":"ping"}{"datatype":"ping"}
```

I'm not sure if node.js is re-sending the data, or if prototype is storing the data. What I need to do is have `response.responseText =` *the last data sent without using `res.end();`*

Comment: Have you forgotten to reset your response inside a loop?

Comment: I thought the response object is completely re-built for each onInteractive. Could you show me how I can reset it?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling `this.pushconnection` more than once.

If you instantiate `this.pushconnection` as it's own Ajax Object and continue to use the same ajax object then your response will grow.

Try this instead:

```
this.pushconnection = function (pushserveraddress) {
  return new Ajax.Request(pushserveraddress, {
    method: 'get',
    evalJSON: 'false',
    onInteractive: this.pushconnectionInteractive.bind(this)
  });
}
```

Then you can call this by saying:

```
var ajax = this.pushconnection("example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

every response add to previous one, to get last object sent if u use that php function :
(1st add headers)

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('connection: keep-alive');
```

(2 send data)

```
function send_message($data_array) {
echo json_encode($data_array).PHP_EOL;
ob_flush();
flush();
```

}

in your js (Prototype): to get last response

```
new Ajax.Request(sUrl, {
onInteractive:function(xhr){
var lastString = xhr.responseText.split("\n");
var lastObjectSent = lastString[lastString.length-2].evalJSON();
if(lastObjectSent.bValid){
    if(parseInt(lastObjectSent.bValid,10) === 1){
        this.status="finished";
        loadPage('done.php');
    }else{
        setNotification(oResult.sText,"Failure",5000);
    }
    }else if(lastObjectSent.progress){
    $('duplicatePassDates').down('.bar').setStyle('width:'+lastObjectSent.progress+'px');
}
},
onSuccess:function(xhr){
if(this.status!=="finished"){
    this.onInteractive(xhr);
}
},
```